# Proper way of converting int to LPCWSTR (Win32)

Tags: c, winapi, type-conversion

I'm attempting to learn basic Win32 programming and running into a frustrating problem. I wish to convert a variable (Call it NumClicks) and display it as the application name (as part of a string).
From what I've seen, going from int + some block of text to a char* is problematic, because converting it to the requisite end data type(LPCWSTR) is more difficult than a straight casting.

Any ideas or links?

Answer (score 5):

use [wsprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647550(VS.85).aspx)
It allows you to compose a string the same way printf allows you to print a line of text.

Comment: In which way it doesn't fully solve your problem? By the way, you'd better use the more secure (and still standard) wsnprintf.

Answer (score 3):

[**_itow**_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h%28VS.80%29.aspx)

If you're looking for more than just INT to LPWSTR conversion (such as formatting), I'd suggest [**StringCchPrintfW**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647541%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used, when I needed LPCWSTR:

```
int f =55;  
wchar_t buffer[10];
_itow_s (f, buffer, 10);
func_using_lpcwstr_as_parameter(buffer);
```

watch for buffer overflows in this sample

Answer (score -2):

rather than use wsprintf i would use sprinf(buf, "%S", "plain old string");

Comment: With the result that you don't get a wide string, which instead is what he need (LPCWSTR = const __wchar_t__ *).